# Add css pseudo element such as ::before and ::after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to add css pseudo element `::before` via jquery on page load?

For example, my css has following rule

```
.temp: :before{border-right: 100px solid transparent; }
```

I want border width same as screen width

Comment: better go with classes on this

Comment: if its on page load why do you need javascript?

Comment: how can I set border width same as screen width?

Comment: why do you need the border width the same as screen width man??

Comment: I set div in triangle shape using div border and I want it responsive if I set same width as screen It will works good.

Comment: use % numbers or vw